# Mongoose Filter & Sort Array of Objects Using Aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm new in Nodejs and Mongodb.
I have schema like this:

```
var x= new Schema({
        title: string,
        articles: [{
            article_date: Date    
            seq: Number
        }]
    }),
Book = mongoose.model('Book', orderSchema);
```

I have data like this:

```
{
  title: "a",
  articles: [
    {article_dt: "2023-05-09T00:00:00.000+00:00", seq:1},
    {article_dt: "2021-12-31T00:00:00.000+00:00", seq:2},
    {article_dt: "2022-12-31T00:00:00.000+00:00", seq:3}
  ]
}
```

I want to show the data based on parameter article_date and sort article_date desc.

I've tried this and i can filter the data based on parameter

```
let paramDate: Date
Book.aggregate([{
    $project:{
        articles:{
            $filter:{
                input: '$articles',
                    as: 'art',
                        cond: {$lt: ['$$art.article_dt', paramDate]}
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

But i dont know how to sort the array. I want to sort desc.
I've tried this https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/
but it wont work..

I'm using:
Mongoose 6.11.1
Node 16.16.0
Mongodb 5.0.9

Please help

Comment: Just read the doc: "***$sortArray**: New in version 5.2.*". You run 5.0.9

Comment: Ah.. i see.. but on the other hand, i dont know how to sort. i've tried using {$sort: 'articles.article_dt': -1} below {$project} and still doesnt work

Comment: I think you need to `$unwind`, then `$sort` and then revert with `$group`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      articles: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$articles",
          as: "art",
          cond: {
            $lt: [
              "$$art.article_dt",
              "2023-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$articles"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "articles.article_dt": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "articles": {
        "$push": {
          article_dt: "$articles.article_dt",
          seq: "$articles.seq"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xZtt2KQ5_QF)